# How to display image on JLabel from JTable selected index?

Tags: java, string, swing, jtable, jlabel

I want to display image from `JTable` selected index text. For example, if selected index `text = jeans`, I want to display on `JLabel` jeans image. But my code doesn't work. I can't display image to label.

Here's the code:

```
private void jTable1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     

   DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();

    // get the selected row index
   int selectedRowIndex = jTable1.getSelectedRow();

    // set the selected row data into jtextfields
   jTextField1.setText(model.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, 0).toString());
   jTextField2.setText(model.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, 1).toString());
   jTextField3.setText(model.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, 4).toString());


   String strJeans ="Jeans";

    ImageIcon imageresult = null;
    if(jTextField3.getText()==strJeans)
    {
            icon = new ImageIcon(icon.getImage().getScaledInstance(100, 100, BufferedImage.SCALE_SMOOTH));
            jLabelPic.setIcon(icon);  
    }

    else
    {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "err");  
    }
    jLabelPic.setIcon(imageresult);
}
```

Comment: so... what's the problem?

Comment: I can tell you already that you should *not* be comparing Strings in java with `==`.

Comment: You are comparing your string with `==` instead of `equals`. Why?

Comment: it doesnt work, jlabel doesnt display image

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Also, are you sure you want to create an `ImageIcon` containing the previous `icon`'s image?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556). E.G. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/418556) hot links to an image embedded in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10861852/418556). 3) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Answer (score 0):

After your if/else statement you call `jLabelPic.setIcon(imageresult);` where `imageresult` is `null`

Comment: I delete that statement, but result same. Doesnt work